# Finding the first instance of words in python

Tags: python

I've been coding a program to find the first instance of each unique word in a sentence but my code doesn't work. I've tried to find a solution but I can't seem to be able to find one. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
csentence= input("Please enter a sentance, ") 
split_sentence=sentence.split
words=[ ]

for x, y in enumerate(words,1):
    if split_sentence .count(y)>1:
        words.append(sentence_split.index(y+1))
    else:
        words.append(x+1)

print(words)
```

Comment: You missed the `()` at `sentence.split`. You are misspelling `split_sentence` and `csentence`

Comment: Please define *"doesn't work"*. If you are getting a traceback, please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: @LPK Thanks, Ive corrected the spellings and added `()` to `sentence.split` but all that is displayed when i run the program is `[ ]` when i should display numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```
def get_word_positions(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    uniques = set(words)

    for word in uniques:
        yield word, words.index(word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
    print(list(get_word_positions(sentence)))
```

**Example Run**

```
Please enter a sentence: The fox is a silly fox indeed a
[('The', 0), ('a', 3), ('is', 2), ('indeed', 6), ('silly', 4), ('fox', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

split is a function. Therefore, you need to use split()

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to split the words into a list:

```
words = sentence.split()
```

Then you can use a dictionary to store the first occurrence of each word:

```
word_occurrences = {}
for word in words:
    word_occurrences[word] = words.index(word)
```

With:

```
sentence = "hi there hi to you there hi"
```

this results in:

```
word_occurrences = {'hi': 0, 'you': 4, 'to': 3, 'there': 1}
```

This can be tidied into a dictionary comprehension using:

```
words = sentence.split()    
word_occurrences = {word:words.index(word) for word in words}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
csentence= input("Please enter a sentence, ") 
split_sentence=csentence.split() # added brackets & changed sentence to csentence
word_index=[]
words=[]
for x,y in enumerate(split_sentence):   
    print(x,y)   
    if y not in words:
        words.append(y)        
        word_index.append(x)

print(word_index)
```